# Como pasar el día de una fecha a el valor en letras y en español en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo la siguiente consulta que trata de sacar la fecha en el siguiente formato

> “Lunes, el Décimo de Noviembre, 2001”

Mi consulta es la siguiente

```
select emp_nombre, 
        emp_fechacontrato,
        initcap(to_char(next_day(add_months(emp_fechacontrato, 3),'LUNES'),'fmDAY, "el" fmDDSPTH  "de" fmMONTH, fmYYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH')) as "Fecha revisada"
from empleados;
```

sin embargo el formato de mi salida es este:

> Lunes, El Twelfth  De Noviembre, 2001

Y el día (Twelfth) no esta en español, quisiera saber como lograr que me de el formato en español

Answer (score 2):

Según la [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-515DFB76-E853-432F-BFEC-F1C62306BEC5):

*Cuando agrega uno de estos sufijos a un elemento de formato de fecha y hora, el valor devuelto siempre está en inglés.*